# Strange Font Issue with Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, css

There seems to be an issue with HelveticaNeue in chrome, on Windows 7. If I manually edit the fontface using dev tools I can get the text to display in the default font. Doing a bit of searching online and this seems to be a bit of chrome bug for certain people, so is there any way to change the font altogether for the cp? Or a chrome fix?

[image: craft font issue]

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not a good idea to go in and change the fonts for Craft yourself.

Please submit a bug report to support@pixelandtonic.com, and they will have a look into the issue.

Comment: As a temporary fix I used the CPCSS Plugin to override the font styling with a nice google font alternate, but I will do ahead and submit a bug report thanks.